# Cutting a Portion of Canvas and Saving it as an Image

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm drawing a Rectangle on a Canvas created from a Bitmap using this method

```
    //void android.graphics.Canvas.drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)
    mycanvas.drawRect(arg1,..arg4,mypaint);
```

I want to show this rectangular portion of the image in an ImageView.

How can i do it? Do i need to create a new Bitmap?

Comment: Have a look at the [`Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap, int, int, int, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method.

Comment: @MikeM. This results in error since the width is getting greater than that of the original bitmap.

Comment: Not sure how that's happening. If you're drawing a rectangle on a `Bitmap`, isn't that rectangle smaller than the `Bitmap`?

Comment: @MikeM.  `x.drawRect((int) (myMidPoint.x - myvalue1* 2),
               (int) (myMidPoint.y - myvalue2* 2),
               (int) (myMidPoint.x + myvalue3* 2),
               (int) (myMidPoint.y + myvalue4* 2), myPaint); ` This what im doing

Comment: @MikeM. To create a new Bitmap i do `bmOverlay =  Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap, (int) (myMidPoint.x - myvalue1* 2),  (int) (myMidPoint.y - myvalue2* 2), (int) (myMidPoint.x + myvalue3* 2), (int) (myMidPoint.y + myvalue4* 2));`

Comment: When you draw a `Rect`, you pass `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`. The fourth parameter in that `createBitmap()` method is the `width`, which would be `right - left`, not just `right`. Similar for the fifth parameter, `height`.